# Azure Queue Storage used in Webjob: How to notify user? (node.js)

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket, queue, message-queue

my plan is to use the azure queue storage between the web app and a webjob. The app receives a job from the user (for example the user enters an URL); the app sends the message to the queue; the webjob receives the message in the queue with the URL and takes & saves a screenshot from the page.

Now how can the webjob notifies the app/user that the job is done and that the picture was saved? I thought about websockets; but websockets doesn't work in webjobs.

So any good ideas?

Thank you very much and best regards!

See basic setup:

- [Microsoft Azure: How to use Queue storage from Node.js](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-queues/)
- [Example how to use Queue storage with node.js in a webjob](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/07/azure-webjobs-with-node-js.aspx)
- [Azure Queue listener example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-queue)

Comment: You could explore [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), I would use [this](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/communicate-from-azure-webjob-with-signalr) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, web sockets is a great way to accomplish that and you *can* use web sockets from within a web job. Here's some sample code...

```
// this is app.js
// one of the code file types that web jobs will take is a .js file
// keep in mind that you have to deploy the node_modules
// folder with the socket.io-client module in it for this web job to work

var socket = require('socket.io-client')('<socket server>');
socket.emit('update', 'socket msg from web job');
```

I've done this before with good success.
Keep in mind that message queues are a very decoupled technology, and web sockets are a very coupled. You may want to have some retry and validation logic that makes sure that messages have arrived if that's important to you.